# Drag and drop trouble

Tags: c#, .net, winrt-xaml

The grid view moves, but when I want to drag to any position it comes back to the start position. What exactly am I doing wrong? I think I'm almost there to finish this drag and drop.

Code:

```
private void gridSlider_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var _GridView = sender as Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.GridView;
    _GridView.RenderTransform = null;

    var _Column = System.Convert.ToInt32(_GridView.GetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty));
    if (_Column <= 0 && e.Cumulative.Translation.X > _GridView.RenderSize.Width * .5)
    {
        _GridView.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 1);
    }
    else if (_Column == 1 && e.Cumulative.Translation.X < _GridView.RenderSize.Width * -.5)
    {
        _GridView.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 0);
    }

    var _Row = System.Convert.ToInt32(_GridView.GetValue(Grid.RowProperty));
    if (_Row <= 0 && e.Cumulative.Translation.Y > _GridView.RenderSize.Height * .5)
        _GridView.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 1);
    else if (_Row == 1 && e.Cumulative.Translation.Y < _GridView.RenderSize.Height * -.5)
        _GridView.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 0);
}

private void gridSlider_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var _GridView = sender as Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.GridView;
    var _Transform = (_GridView.RenderTransform = (_GridView.RenderTransform as TranslateTransform) ?? new TranslateTransform()) as TranslateTransform;
    _Transform.X += e.Delta.Translation.X;
    _Transform.Y += e.Delta.Translation.Y;
}
```

Xaml code:

```
 <StackPanel Name="TransportControlsPanel" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" Margin="351,0,0,0" >
      <GridView x:Name="gridSlider" Width="604" AllowDrop="True" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="92" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Collapsed" SelectionMode="None" ManipulationCompleted="gridSlider_ManipulationCompleted" ManipulationDelta="gridSlider_ManipulationDelta">

           <Slider x:Name="timelineSlider" AllowDrop="True" Margin="200,0,10,49" Width="192" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Collapsed" Background="Gray"/>

      </GridView>
 </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This is a much more complete example than your last (deleted) question. In the future, please keep in mind that it is preferred to edit the question (using the edit button below your post) instead of deleting and re-posting.

Comment: I'm confused as to what you are trying to do. Do you have a `GridView` with items in it that you'd like to be able to control with a 'remote' via a slider, as opposed to the horizontal scroll bar? Or do you have a series of sliders you want displayed in a GridView?